# Update both primary table and foreign key table in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have 2 tables in mysql database:

Table "customers"
id [pk] | brandname | taxnumber | email | excel_id [fk]

Table "excel"
id [pk] | filename | enable

I want to add the name of the excel file on column "filename" and additionally i want to update customers. excel_id with the value of excel.id

i have implemented relations and foreing key with "on update cascade" and "on delete cascade".

Trying to run the following code:

```
Excel::import(new CustomerImport, $request->file('file'));
DB::insert('insert into excel (filename) values (?)', [$request->get('filename')]);
DB::table('excel')
          ->where('filename', $request->get('filename'))
          ->update(['customers.excel_id' => 'id']);
```

Comment: Does `Excel::import(new CustomerImport, $request->file('file'));` return an object which contains `id` which you want to insert int `excel_id` column? What is the relation between Customer & Excel model - Customer belongsTo Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found a solution. I have to use insertGetId method to get the id from the table and to update customers.excel_id with this.

```
Excel::import(new CustomerImport, $request->file('file'));
$dbid = DB::table('excel')->insertGetId(['filename' => $request->get('filename')]);
DB::table('customers')->where('excel_id', NULL ) ->update(['excel_id' => $dbid]);
```